# Entity Framework Code First Configure Schema Per Entity

Tags: linq-to-sql, mapping, ef-code-first, entity-framework-4.1

In LINQ to SQL there is a very simple convention to tell the mapper what database schema to use - `[Table(Name = "SchemaName.TableName")]`.

Is there something similar in EF CF 4.1? I would rather not use annotations in the entity classes to keep them as pure as possible. For the sake of keeping my project moving I'll make the sacrifice though.

This question is close, but not exactly what I need. It may even be outdated as it looks like it's referring to classes that have been renamed or have had breaking changes since the recent EF 4.1 release - [Entity Framework 4: Code First - Creating db in another schema? MapSingleType?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4841847/entity-framework-4-code-first-creating-db-in-another-schema-mapsingletype)

EDIT: I should also mention that my application has three schemas at the moment, so I can't necessarily use a solution that changes only the default schema from "dbo" to "otherschema".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The linked answer is old and it doesn't work because custom conventions were removed from final version. If you want to change name of schema you can use fluent api:

```
public class Context : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<YourType> YourTypeSet { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        modelBuilder.Entity<YourType>().ToTable("TableName", "SchemaName");
    }
}
```

Comment: I want to set table name automatically and set schema manually! but How? there should be a method like ToSchema()... but it's not